# Python3 + Tor's stem library => Permission denied when creating new hidden service

Tags: python, stem

I am trying to deploy a new hidden service using Tor's stem library for Python3, but I am always receiving errors that the service can not be created due to '**[Errno 13] Permission denied**' issue.
I am actually just copying, pasting and modifying (the password) this code https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/over_the_river.html and running it from my Ubuntu 20.10 machine.

The exact **Python3 code** I am running is:

```
import os
import shutil
 
from stem.control import Controller
from flask import Flask
 
app = Flask(__name__)
 
 
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return "<h1>Hi Grandma!</h1>"
 
 
print(' * Connecting to tor')
 
with Controller.from_port(port=9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate(password="my_password")
 
  # All hidden services have a directory on disk. Lets put ours in tor's data
  # directory.
 
  hidden_service_dir = os.path.join(controller.get_conf('DataDirectory', '/tmp'), 'hello_world')
  print(hidden_service_dir)
  # Create a hidden service where visitors of port 80 get redirected to local
  # port 5000 (this is where Flask runs by default).
 
  print(" * Creating our hidden service in %s" % hidden_service_dir)
  result = controller.create_hidden_service(hidden_service_dir, 80, target_port = 5000) # THIS returns None and says Permission denied
 
  # The hostname is only available when we can read the hidden service
  # directory. This requires us to be running with the same user as tor.
 
  if result.hostname:
    print(" * Our service is available at %s, press ctrl+c to quit" % result.hostname)
  else:
    print(" * Unable to determine our service's hostname, probably due to being unable to read the hidden service directory")
 
  try:
    app.run()
  finally:
    # Shut down the hidden service and clean it off disk. Note that you *don't*
    # want to delete the hidden service directory if you'd like to have this
    # same *.onion address in the future.
 
    print(" * Shutting down our hidden service")
    controller.remove_hidden_service(hidden_service_dir)
    shutil.rmtree(hidden_service_dir)
```

And this is the **torrc config** file:

```
## Configuration file for a typical Tor user
## Last updated 9 October 2013 for Tor 0.2.5.2-alpha.
## (may or may not work for much older or much newer versions of Tor.)
##
## Lines that begin with "## " try to explain what's going on. Lines
## that begin with just "#" are disabled commands: you can enable them
## by removing the "#" symbol.
##
## See 'man tor', or https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html,
## for more options you can use in this file.
##
## Tor will look for this file in various places based on your platform:
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#torrc
 
## Tor opens a socks proxy on port 9050 by default -- even if you don't
## configure one below. Set "SocksPort 0" if you plan to run Tor only
## as a relay, and not make any local application connections yourself.
#SocksPort 9050 # Default: Bind to localhost:9050 for local connections.
#SocksPort 192.168.0.1:9100 # Bind to this address:port too.
 
## Entry policies to allow/deny SOCKS requests based on IP address.
## First entry that matches wins. If no SocksPolicy is set, we accept
## all (and only) requests that reach a SocksPort. Untrusted users who
## can access your SocksPort may be able to learn about the connections
## you make.
#SocksPolicy accept 192.168.0.0/16
#SocksPolicy reject *
 
## Logs go to stdout at level "notice" unless redirected by something
## else, like one of the below lines. You can have as many Log lines as
## you want.
##
## We advise using "notice" in most cases, since anything more verbose
## may provide sensitive information to an attacker who obtains the logs.
##
## Send all messages of level 'notice' or higher to /var/log/tor/notices.log
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
## Send every possible message to /var/log/tor/debug.log
Log debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
## Use the system log instead of Tor's logfiles
#Log notice syslog
## To send all messages to stderr:
#Log debug stderr
 
## Uncomment this to start the process in the background... or use
## --runasdaemon 1 on the command line. This is ignored on Windows;
## see the FAQ entry if you want Tor to run as an NT service.
#RunAsDaemon 1
 
## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc. By default, we store
## things in $HOME/.tor on Unix, and in Application Data\tor on Windows.
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
 
## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
HashedControlPassword 16:163032F0D98F2EE9609CF54B51877BBBE4A065733EA7785BE5EE1E2026
 
CookieAuthentication 1
DataDirectoryGroupReadable 1
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
ExtORPortCookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
CacheDirectoryGroupReadable 1
CookieAuthFile /var/lib/tor/control_auth_cookie
 
############### This section is just for location-hidden services ###
 
## Once you have configured a hidden service, you can look at the
## contents of the file ".../hidden_service/hostname" for the address
## to tell people.
##
## HiddenServicePort x y:z says to redirect requests on port x to the
## address y:z.
 
#HiddenServiceDir /tmp/tor/
#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:5000
 
#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/other_hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
#HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
 
################ This section is just for relays #####################
#
## See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-relay for details.
 
## Required: what port to advertise for incoming Tor connections.
#ORPort 9001
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## ORPort (e.g. to advertise 443 but bind to 9090), you can do it as
## follows.  You'll need to do ipchains or other port forwarding
## yourself to make this work.
#ORPort 443 NoListen
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:9090 NoAdvertise
 
## The IP address or full DNS name for incoming connections to your
## relay. Leave commented out and Tor will guess.
#Address noname.example.com
 
## If you have multiple network interfaces, you can specify one for
## outgoing traffic to use.
# OutboundBindAddress 10.0.0.5
 
## A handle for your relay, so people don't have to refer to it by key.
#Nickname ididnteditheconfig
 
## Define these to limit how much relayed traffic you will allow. Your
## own traffic is still unthrottled. Note that RelayBandwidthRate must
## be at least 20 KB.
## Note that units for these config options are bytes per second, not bits
## per second, and that prefixes are binary prefixes, i.e. 2^10, 2^20, etc.
#RelayBandwidthRate 100 KB  # Throttle traffic to 100KB/s (800Kbps)
#RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KB # But allow bursts up to 200KB/s (1600Kbps)
 
## Use these to restrict the maximum traffic per day, week, or month.
## Note that this threshold applies separately to sent and received bytes,
## not to their sum: setting "4 GB" may allow up to 8 GB total before
## hibernating.
##
## Set a maximum of 4 gigabytes each way per period.
#AccountingMax 4 GB
## Each period starts daily at midnight (AccountingMax is per day)
#AccountingStart day 00:00
## Each period starts on the 3rd of the month at 15:00 (AccountingMax
## is per month)
#AccountingStart month 3 15:00
 
## Administrative contact information for this relay or bridge. This line
## can be used to contact you if your relay or bridge is misconfigured or
## something else goes wrong. Note that we archive and publish all
## descriptors containing these lines and that Google indexes them, so
## spammers might also collect them. You may want to obscure the fact that
## it's an email address and/or generate a new address for this purpose.
#ContactInfo Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>
## You might also include your PGP or GPG fingerprint if you have one:
#ContactInfo 0xFFFFFFFF Random Person <nobody AT example dot com>
 
## Uncomment this to mirror directory information for others. Please do
## if you have enough bandwidth.
#DirPort 9030 # what port to advertise for directory connections
## If you want to listen on a port other than the one advertised in
## DirPort (e.g. to advertise 80 but bind to 9091), you can do it as
## follows.  below too. You'll need to do ipchains or other port
## forwarding yourself to make this work.
#DirPort 80 NoListen
#DirPort 127.0.0.1:9091 NoAdvertise
## Uncomment to return an arbitrary blob of html on your DirPort. Now you
## can explain what Tor is if anybody wonders why your IP address is
## contacting them. See contrib/tor-exit-notice.html in Tor's source
## distribution for a sample.
#DirPortFrontPage /etc/tor/tor-exit-notice.html
 
## Uncomment this if you run more than one Tor relay, and add the identity
## key fingerprint of each Tor relay you control, even if they're on
## different networks. You declare it here so Tor clients can avoid
## using more than one of your relays in a single circuit. See
## https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#MultipleRelays
## However, you should never include a bridge's fingerprint here, as it would
## break its concealability and potentionally reveal its IP/TCP address.
#MyFamily $keyid,$keyid,...
 
## A comma-separated list of exit policies. They're considered first
## to last, and the first match wins. If you want to _replace_
## the default exit policy, end this with either a reject *:* or an
## accept *:*. Otherwise, you're _augmenting_ (prepending to) the
## default exit policy. Leave commented to just use the default, which is
## described in the man page or at
## https://www.torproject.org/documentation.html
##
## Look at https://www.torproject.org/faq-abuse.html#TypicalAbuses
## for issues you might encounter if you use the default exit policy.
##
## If certain IPs and ports are blocked externally, e.g. by your firewall,
## you should update your exit policy to reflect this -- otherwise Tor
## users will be told that those destinations are down.
##
## For security, by default Tor rejects connections to private (local)
## networks, including to your public IP address. See the man page entry
## for ExitPolicyRejectPrivate if you want to allow "exit enclaving".
##
#ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:* # allow irc ports but no more
#ExitPolicy accept *:119 # accept nntp as well as default exit policy
#ExitPolicy reject *:* # no exits allowed
 
## Bridge relays (or "bridges") are Tor relays that aren't listed in the
## main directory. Since there is no complete public list of them, even an
## ISP that filters connections to all the known Tor relays probably
## won't be able to block all the bridges. Also, websites won't treat you
## differently because they won't know you're running Tor. If you can
## be a real relay, please do; but if not, be a bridge!
#BridgeRelay 1
## By default, Tor will advertise your bridge to users through various
## mechanisms like https://bridges.torproject.org/. If you want to run
## a private bridge, for example because you'll give out your bridge
## address manually to your friends, uncomment this line:
#PublishServerDescriptor 0
```

Any ideas what is going on?
I have tried to chmod and chown the directories and files in /var/lib/tor to debian-tor user, but without any luck. So, this is how it looks now:

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/tor

total 10076
-rwx------ 1 debian-tor debian-tor   20472 feb 11 09:12 cached-certs
-rwx------ 1 debian-tor debian-tor 2277055 feb 11 15:52 cached-microdesc-consensus
-rwx------ 1 debian-tor debian-tor 7918599 feb 11 09:42 cached-microdescs
-rwx------ 1 debian-tor debian-tor   63812 feb 11 15:56 cached-microdescs.new
-rw-r----- 1 debian-tor debian-tor      32 feb 11 16:29 control_auth_cookie
drwx--S--- 3 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 feb 11 16:29 hello_world
drwx--S--- 3 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 feb 11 15:40 hidden_service
drwx--S--- 2 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 jan 26 14:42 keys
-rwx------ 1 debian-tor debian-tor       0 feb 11 16:29 lock
-rw------- 1 debian-tor debian-tor    5005 feb 11 16:31 state
drwx--S--- 3 debian-tor debian-tor    4096 feb 11 16:21 x
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Just to note:** The exact same config on my Raspberry Pi gives me the same issue - Permission denied.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: The issue in the Python code seems to be exactly on this line:

```
result = controller.create_hidden_service(hidden_service_dir, 80, target_port = 5000)
```

Comment: Your code says "The hostname is only available when we can read the hidden service directory. This requires us to be running with the same user as tor". Are you running your script as the same user? If you're using the tor systemd service instead of running a separate tor instance on the command line, then you probably want to look into using an [ephemeral onion service](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/over_the_river.html#ephemeral-hidden-services) instead.

Comment: Hi @Steve , I am running my service as the 'pi' user on Raspberry Pi and the equivalent (normal, not 'tor' user) on Ubuntu machine.  Can you please elaborate more on this as how to run the Python script to make it work?

Comment: To make it work you will need to run it as the 'debian-tor' user. So you could run your script as `sudo -u debian-tor script.py`. But I definitely recommend either using an ephemeral service, or running your own tor process instead which uses a DataDirectory in your home directory (this is what atagar did in their tutorial).

Comment: Thank you! Running an ephemeral service fixed the issue. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks again!